# In python, how do you import all classes from another module without keeping the imported module's namespace?

Tags: python

How do you import classes and methods from another module without retaining the former module namespace?

I am current refactoring some legacy code and am frequently doing imports similar to these.

```
from legacy_module import ClassA as ClassA
from legacy_module import ClassB as ClassB
from legacy_module import ClassC as ClassC
from legacy_module import methodA as methodA
from legacy_module import methodB as methodB
```

This is done so that the classes can be referenced as ClassA rather than legacy_module.ClassA.

In python, how do you import all of the classes and methods above in a single statement?

```
from legacy_module import * as *
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use `from legacy_module import *` as your entire import.

Comment: In python 3.6, I have to add "." before the file name: `from .legacy_module import * `

Comment: it will not work if you would like to use globals()[nameOfClass]

Comment: Well hopefully you're not doing that because it's a terrible practice.