# Python3: How to provide module exports as convenience at the package level?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package

Hopefully my question won't get me into the Python Hall of Shame.

Anyway, I have a package `poo` that currently contains only a single module `moo`. In the future, there might be additional modules inside `poo` (such as `poo.moose`). Let's assume that `moo` is kind of a main-use module and that users want to have all things in `moo` ready at hand when they import `poo`, the package. I (and my package users) would like to avoid `import poo.moo`, `import poo.moo as moo`, and (gasp!) `import poo.*`. You know, saving typing is a good thing.

So my idea (which is hopefully not completely off the right way) is to copy the "exports" (functions, variables, classes, ...) of module `poo.moo` to package `poo`, in `__init.py__`. I don't want to overwrite any existing definitions in `poo` though.

What is a correct, good, proper, and efficient way to achieve this? (Did I use "ideal"? Nah!) Or is that a bad idea at all? Or is this highly spirited Python in the sense of "...and now for something completely different"? ;)

Oh, my packages are Python3 only.

Please note that [In python, how do you import all classes from another module without keeping the imported module's namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980062) has the answer, but did not understand how this would also apply to the `__init__.py` code of a Python package. For this reason, my detailed answer below gives such additional details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In python, how do you import all classes from another module without keeping the imported module's namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980062/in-python-how-do-you-import-all-classes-from-another-module-without-keeping-the)

Comment: @ppperry unfortunately, a `from x import * as *` doesn't work with Python3.

Comment: Delete the `as *`.

Comment: @ppperry thank you, that's it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out to be really easy. In the package `poo/__init__.py` simply do this (absolute) import of the module into the package namespace:

```
from poo.moo import *
```

That's it. Now when there's a `poo.moo.a()` it will become accessible as `poo.a()` too.

Please note that package definitions aren't overwritten by the (sub) module import, as was my intention: `poo.moo.version=42` doesn't overwrite `poo.version=13`. Exactly what is needed.

I now notice that I'm still addled by those other modularized languages where imports stay private to a module. But in Python all is in plain view, so are package imports in a module/package.